# spring rabbitMQ new listener on each message

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq

I have a spring rabbit listener in the project. I want to have run it in a brand new thread on every message event. So, a message goes from the rabbitMQ queue to the system, and spring launches listener in another separate thread.
Is it possible? I tried to make my listener bean as prototype, but no luck. What I need to do to achieve the result? Thank you

```
public class Rabbit {
@Bean
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory(){
    CachingConnectionFactory f=new CachingConnectionFactory();
    f.setHost("127.0.0.1");
    f.setPassword("123");
    f.setPort(5672);
    f.setUsername("root");
    return f;
}

final static String QUEUE_NAME = "queueOrderSaver";

@Bean
public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate(){
    RabbitTemplate t=new RabbitTemplate();
    t.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
    t.setRoutingKey("queue.*");
    t.setExchange("exchange");
    return t;
}

@Bean
public RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(){
    return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
public TopicExchange exchange(){
    return new TopicExchange("exchange");
}

@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME);
}

@Bean
Binding binding(Queue q, TopicExchange e) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(q).to(e).with(QUEUE_NAME);
}

@Bean
SimpleMessageListenerContainer container(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer container = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer();
    container.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    //container.setConcurrentConsumers(20);
    container.setQueueNames(QUEUE_NAME);
    container.setMessageListener(listenerAdapter);
    return container;
}

@Bean
MessageListenerAdapter listenerAdapter() {
    return new MessageListenerAdapter(worker);
}


}
```

Comment: Why? Seems like an [XY](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Spring has a [thread pool](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html) for processing incoming messages. Spinning up a new thread is **expensive** so they are recycled.

Comment: Under load this would more than likely cause more problems. If performance is what you are after, and I am guessing that is what you are trying to do, this is not how to go about it. Rather give some detail to the problem that needs solving

Comment: Thanks, but I have a heavy logic, and one of the requirements of the project is to run every message in a separate thread. Do you think it's better not to use concurrency at all because it's expensive to create a thread?

Comment: Moreover, I will have minimum and maximum adjustable number  of threads which listener may process simultaneously

Comment: What? You say you want process every message **in its own thread**. Then you say a viable alternative is to process all messages on **the same thread**. Now you say you want to process messages on a **fixed number of threads**. Could you please succinctly and carefully explain **what you want**?

Comment: Sorry for unclear explanations and thanks for response. The system should work in the following way. We have a rabbitmq queue. When queue sends a message to our listener, listener invoke special method. Lets call it listen(). I thought that this method will run in the separate thread for every message, but I felt that it`s not so. I also have minimum, and maximum number of threads that are running at this moment. And are processing one message each. If new message comes and maximum number reached, message rejected. I hope I explained clearly.

Comment: So in my case I probably have to start a new thread in listen() method, and make number of threads in listener